# Pandas - Plotting series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is indexed by a datetime column and I get value_count() for various time ranges.  For example,

```
data['leadsource_ch_disp_name'].ix[rng[0]].value_counts()
```

returns

```
Unknown        223
Sponsorship    889
Reseller       145
Referral        52
dtype: int64
```

which is a series.  I want to do this with 5 different time ranges (`rng[i]` for i=[0,..,4]).  So then I am left with 5 series.  What I want to do is plot these 5 series (on the same plot) such that the x-axis is the series name and the y-axis is the values.  And I want it to be a line graph with 4 lines (for unknown, sponsorship, reseller, and referral).

I have tried the following

```
rng0=data['leadsource_ch_disp_name'].ix[rng[0]].value_counts()
rng1=data['leadsource_ch_disp_name'].ix[rng[1]].value_counts()
rng2=data['leadsource_ch_disp_name'].ix[rng[2]].value_counts()
rng3=data['leadsource_ch_disp_name'].ix[rng[3]].value_counts()
rng4=data['leadsource_ch_disp_name'].ix[rng[4]].value_counts()
rng5=data['leadsource_ch_disp_name'].ix[rng[5]].value_counts()
pd.concat([rng0,rng1,rng2,rng3,rng4,rng5],axis=1).plot()
```

however, this does not return what I want.  This creates a plot where the x-axis is Referral,reseller,sponsorship,unknown and there are 5 lines for the 5 different series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `plot()` draws a line for each column, try transposing the frame first..

```
pd.concat([rng0,rng1,rng2,rng3,rng4,rng5],axis=1).T.plot()
```

Comment: Wow. I thought it would be more complicated than that :) Thanks!